# pdksh missing from RHEL 6 and CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, ksh

The package `pdksh` does not exist on RHEL 6 or CentOS 6 when I try to install it through `yum`.

So my questions:

1. Why is it no longer available in the default repositories? It is available in version 5.x.
2. Is there a replacement shell?
3. What about programs that depend on `pdksh`? Can they use the replacement shell?

My workaround has been to use the package from version 5, which I feel is not the proper solution and I should understand it better than the workaround.

My concern is mainly regarding Oracle Database. It asks for `pdksh`, so will it be a problem to use a replacment shell other than `pdksh`?

Comment: Maybe [`mksh`](http://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) could make you happy, too? -- "a successor to the
 Public Domain Korn Shell (pdksh)"

Comment: hi, I have no problem at all with any package, my question is related to the technical side! if I install mksh does an application depends on pdksh still working even if it requests the pdksh and there is mksh instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was under the impression that pdksh was not POSIX compliant, and with the release of open source AT&T KSH, there was significant movement from pdksh to [ksh](http://www.kornshell.com/software/). Just my $0.02

AT&T ksh is licensed by the Eclipse Public License 1.0 (EPL-1.0).

Comment: You are confusing open source and public domain but anyway, you are right pdksh is quite a poor reimplementation and the real ksh93 which is freely available is a much better choice.

Comment: open source, public domain, free, license a, b, c
YES, I am confused and frequently use any of the former interchangeably ;)

Comment: my question is related to the technical side! if I install ksh93 does an application depends on pdksh still working even if it requests the pdksh and there is ksh93 instead?

Comment: Unfortunately that depends on the script. You can install the ksh and create a pdksh symlink so the #! she bangs don't break, but script by script there's always the possibility that some "feature" or another might break. Try it an see, be ready to restore the pdksh

Comment: What's missing in pdksh for POSIX compliance? @Data-Base The one major deviation of pdksh from AT&T ksh is that the last command in a pipeline is executed in the parent shell only in AT&T ksh. Apart from that, pdksh is pretty close to AT&T ksh88, and ksh93 is upward compatible with ksh88 except in very unusual cases. Of course, it's never guaranteed that none of your scripts depend on any such unusual case.

Comment: In the RHEL5 package, it says:
`Pdksh is unmaintained since 1998 and is obsoleted by ksh package.`

Answer (score 11):

According to this article "[Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2) Installation On Oracle Linux 6](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/oracle-db-11gr2-installation-on-oracle-linux-6.php)":

*The failure for the "pdksh" package can be ignored because we installed the "ksh" package in its place*

On my fairly standard OEL 6.3 machine, ksh was already installed as part of the build, but you may have to do a `sudo yum install ksh` to install it.

---

Our DBAs also found this article which may be of use:

Installing "11.2.0.3 32-bit (x86)" or "64-bit (x86-64)" on RHEL6 reports that packages `elfutils-libelf-devel-0.97` and `pdksh-5.2.14` are missing.

## Applies to

- Oracle Server - Enterprise Edition - Version 11.2.0.3 to 11.2.0.3 [Release 11.2]
- Oracle Universal Installer - Version 11.2.0.3 to 11.2.0.3 [Release 11.2]
- Oracle Server - Standard Edition - Version 11.2.0.3 to 11.2.0.3 [Release 11.2]
- Linux x86
- Linux x86-64

## Symptoms

While installing

- 11.2.0.3 32-bit (x86) database software on RHEL6 x86 server
- 11.2.0.3 64-bit (x86-64) database software on RHEL6 x86-64 server

the *Oracle Universal Installer* (OUI) reports that packages `elfultils-libelf-devel-0.97` and `pdksh-5.2.14` are missing.

In the `installActions.log` the following output can be observed:

```
INFO: INFO: *********************************************
INFO: INFO: Package: elfutils-libelf-devel-0.97: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the package "elfutils-libelf-devel-0.97" is available on the system.
INFO: INFO: Severity:IGNORABLE
INFO: INFO: OverallStatus:VERIFICATION_FAILED
INFO: INFO: -----------------------------------------------INFO: INFO: Verification Result for Node:nodename
INFO: INFO: Expected Value:elfutils-libelf-devel-0.97
INFO: INFO: Actual Value:missing
INFO: INFO: Error Message:PRVF-7532 : Package "elfutils-libelf-devel" is missing on node "nodename"
INFO: INFO: Cause: A required package is either not installed or, if the package is a kernel module, is not loaded on the specified node.
INFO: INFO: Action: Ensure that the required package is installed and available.
INFO: INFO: -----------------------------------------------:
INFO: INFO: *********************************************
INFO: INFO: Package: pdksh-5.2.14: This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the package "pdksh-5.2.14" is available on the system.
INFO: INFO: Severity:IGNORABLE
INFO: INFO: OverallStatus:VERIFICATION_FAILED
INFO: INFO: -----------------------------------------------INFO: INFO: Verification Result for Node:nodename
INFO: INFO: Expected Value:pdksh-5.2.14
INFO: INFO: Actual Value:missing
INFO: INFO: Error Message:PRVF-7532 : Package "pdksh" is missing on node "nodename"
INFO: INFO: Cause: A required package is either not installed or, if the package is a kernel module, is not loaded on the specified node.
INFO: INFO: Action: Ensure that the required package is installed and available.
INFO: INFO: -----------------------------------------------:
```

## Cause

OUI executes the following command:

```
/bin/rpm -q --qf %{version} redhat-release
```

no output is returned (because in RHEL6 the package redhat-release has been replaced by redhat-release-server-6Server).

This causes OUI to believe that the server is not a RHEL server.

As OUI can not identify what type of server it is, OUI performs the default (OEL4) prerequisite checks.

This problem has been logged as unpublished bug 13981169 with Oracle Development.

In addition to this, no RHEL6 prerequisite checks are defined in

```
<path>/database/stage/cvu/cvu_prereq.xml
```

in the 11.2.0.3 media.

## Solution

### Solution for 11.2.0.3 64-bit (x86-64)

If you have downloaded the 11.2.0.3 media from My Oracle Support (MOS) and extracted the software to `<path>/database`, do the following:

1. Change directory to `<path>/database/stage/cvu/cv/admin`
2. Backup cvu_config `cp cvu_config backup_cvu_config`
3. Edit cvu_config and change the following line `CV_ASSUME_DISTID=OEL4` to `CV_ASSUME_DISTID=OEL6`
4. Save the updated `cvu_config` file
5. Install the 11.2.0.3 software using:

   1. `<path>/database/runInstaller`
   2. `cd <path>/database`
   3. `./runInstaller`

OUI should now perform the OEL6 prerequisite checks (which are identical to the RHEL6 prerequisite checks) and no longer report that packages `elfutils-libelf-devel-0.97` and `pdksh-5.2.14` are missing

#### NOTE

If you have received the 11.2.0.3 media on DVD, it will be necessary to copy the media from the DVD to a disk on the RHEL6 server (so that you can follow the steps above)

### Solution for 11.2.0.3 32-bit (x86)

As the `cvu_prereq.xml` file for 11.2.0.3 32-bit (x86) does not reference RHEL6 or OEL6, the above workaround can not be used.

After manually verifying that all of the requirements have been met, choose the *Ignore all* option in the installer and continue with the installation.

Comment: Works also on RHEL 6.7 with 11.2.0.2.0. Thank you!

Comment: Dude, you can get issue due copyright, you shouldn't share oracle support documentation.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that prior to RHEL 6, Red Hat were wary of the AT&T [KornShell](http://kornshell.com/) because of its licence, so they included the pdksh, which is a less complete implementation. I think David Korn was doing his best to get ksh accepted in as many places as possible and somewhere along the line the licence was clarified or changed. This quote is from the [KornShell](http://kornshell.com/) website: "AT&T has released KornShell as open source".

Obviously Red Hat were satisfied with the licence by the time RHEL 6 was released, so they included "the real thing".

Edit: actually it's explained on the Wikipedia page (of course) - see the first paragraph under History.

Answer (score 0):

I made a patch for an old mandrake 2007.1 rpm package, and created a new SRPM package which one should be able to compile without any problems on modern linux distro's with newer gcc versions:

ftp://ftp.crashrecovery.org/pub/linux/pdksh/RPMS/mdv2011/
ftp://ftp.crashrecovery.org/pub/linux/pdksh/RPMS/mdv2011/pdksh-5.2.14-21-mdv2011.0.x86_64.rpm
ftp://ftp.crashrecovery.org/pub/linux/pdksh/RPMS/mdv2011/pdksh-5.2.14-21.src.rpm
ftp://ftp.crashrecovery.org/pub/linux/pdksh/RPMS/mdv2011/ksh.pdf

Two adjustments were made : inside siglist.sh  : sort +2n +0n is replaced with sort -k3n -k1n and inside several c files shprintf(newline); becomes shprintf("%s", newline); to prevent the -Werror=format-security errors from happening.

```
[vax-linux:root]:(~/rpmbuild/BUILD/pdksh-5.2.14)# make check
./tests/th-sh ./tests/th -s ./tests -p ./ksh -C pdksh,sh,ksh,posix,posix-upu 
pass lineno.t:lineno-stdin
pass lineno.t:lineno-inc
pass lineno.t:lineno-func
pass lineno.t:lineno-unset
pass lineno.t:lineno-unset-use
pass alias.t:alias-1
pass alias.t:alias-2
pass alias.t:alias-3
pass alias.t:alias-4
pass alias.t:alias-5
pass alias.t:alias-6
pass alias.t:alias-7
pass alias.t:alias-8
pass glob.t:glob-bad-1
pass glob.t:glob-range-1
pass glob.t:glob-range-2
pass glob.t:glob-range-3
pass glob.t:glob-range-4
pass glob.t:glob-range-5
pass eglob.t:eglob-bad-1
pass eglob.t:eglob-bad-2
pass eglob.t:eglob-infinite-plus
pass eglob.t:eglob-subst-1
pass eglob.t:eglob-nomatch-1
pass eglob.t:eglob-match-1
pass eglob.t:eglob-case-1
pass eglob.t:eglob-case-2
pass eglob.t:eglob-trim-1
pass eglob.t:eglob-trim-2
pass arith.t:arith-lazy-1
pass arith.t:arith-lazy-2
FAIL arith.t:arith-ternary-prec-1
pass arith.t:arith-ternary-prec-2
pass arith.t:arith-div-assoc-1
pass arith.t:arith-assop-assoc-1
pass history.t:history-basic
pass history.t:history-e-minus-1
pass history.t:history-e-minus-2
pass history.t:history-e-minus-3
pass history.t:history-e-minus-4
pass history.t:history-e-minus-5
pass history.t:history-list-1
pass history.t:history-list-2
pass history.t:history-list-3
pass history.t:history-list-4
pass history.t:history-list-5
pass history.t:history-list-6
pass history.t:history-list-7
pass history.t:history-list-r-1
pass history.t:history-list-r-2
pass history.t:history-list-r-3
pass history.t:history-subst-1
pass history.t:history-subst-2
pass history.t:history-subst-3
pass history.t:history-subst-4
pass history.t:history-subst-5
pass ifs.t:IFS-space-1
pass ifs.t:IFS-colon-1
pass ifs.t:IFS-null-1
pass ifs.t:IFS-space-colon-1
pass ifs.t:IFS-space-colon-2
fail ifs.t:IFS-space-colon-3 (as expected)
pass ifs.t:IFS-space-colon-4
pass ifs.t:IFS-space-colon-5
pass ifs.t:IFS-subst-1
pass brkcont.t:break-1
pass brkcont.t:break-2
pass brkcont.t:break-3
pass brkcont.t:break-4
pass brkcont.t:break-5
pass brkcont.t:continue-1
pass brkcont.t:continue-2
pass brkcont.t:continue-3
pass brkcont.t:continue-4
pass brkcont.t:continue-5
pass syntax.t:syntax-1
pass read.t:read-IFS-1
pass read.t:read-ksh-1
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-1
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-2
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-3
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-4
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-5
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-6
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-7
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-8
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-tmpfile-1
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-tmpfile-2
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-tmpfile-3
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-tmpfile-4
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-tmpfile-5
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-tmpfile-6
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-tmpfile-7
pass heredoc.t:heredoc-tmpfile-8
pass bksl-nl.t:bksl-nl-ign-1
pass bksl-nl.t:bksl-nl-ign-2
pass bksl-nl.t:bksl-nl-ign-3
pass bksl-nl.t:blsk-nl-ign-4
pass bksl-nl.t:blsk-nl-ign-5
pass bksl-nl.t:bksl-nl-1
pass bksl-nl.t:bksl-nl-2
pass bksl-nl.t:bksl-nl-3
pass bksl-nl.t:bksl-nl-4
pass bksl-nl.t:bksl-nl-5
pass bksl-nl.t:bksl-nl-6
pass bksl-nl.t:bksl-nl-7
pass bksl-nl.t:bksl-nl-8
pass bksl-nl.t:blsk-nl-9
pass bksl-nl.t:blsk-nl-10
pass bksl-nl.t:blsk-nl-ksh-1
pass bksl-nl.t:blsk-nl-ksh-2
pass regress.t:regression-1
pass regress.t:regression-2
pass regress.t:regression-6
pass regress.t:regression-9
FAIL regress.t:regression-10
pass regress.t:regression-11
pass regress.t:regression-12
pass regress.t:regression-13
pass regress.t:regression-14
pass regress.t:regression-15
pass regress.t:regression-16
pass regress.t:regression-17
pass regress.t:regression-19
pass regress.t:regression-21
pass regress.t:regression-22
pass regress.t:regression-23
pass regress.t:regression-25
pass regress.t:regression-26
pass regress.t:regression-27
pass regress.t:regression-28
pass regress.t:regression-29
pass regress.t:regression-30
pass regress.t:regression-31
pass regress.t:regression-32
pass regress.t:regression-33
pass regress.t:regression-35
pass regress.t:regression-36
pass regress.t:regression-37
pass regress.t:regression-38
fail regress.t:regression-39 (as expected)
pass regress.t:regression-40
pass regress.t:regression-41
pass regress.t:regression-42
pass regress.t:regression-43
pass regress.t:regression-44
pass regress.t:regression-45
pass regress.t:regression-46
pass regress.t:regression-47
pass regress.t:regression-48
pass regress.t:regression-49
pass regress.t:regression-50
pass regress.t:regression-51
pass regress.t:regression-52
pass regress.t:regression-53
pass regress.t:regression-54
pass regress.t:regression-55
pass regress.t:regression-56
pass regress.t:regression-57
pass regress.t:regression-58
pass regress.t:regression-59
pass regress.t:regression-60
pass regress.t:regression-61
pass regress.t:regression-62
pass version.t:version-1
pass unclass1.t:xxx-quoted-newline-1
pass unclass1.t:xxx-quoted-newline-2
pass unclass1.t:xxx-quoted-newline-3
pass unclass1.t:xxx-multi-assignment-cmd
pass unclass1.t:xxx-exec-environment-1
pass unclass1.t:xxx-what-do-you-call-this-1
pass unclass1.t:xxx-prefix-strip-1
pass unclass1.t:xxx-prefix-strip-2
pass unclass1.t:xxx-variable-syntax-1
pass unclass2.t:xxx-subsitution-eval-order
pass unclass2.t:xxx-set-option-1
pass unclass2.t:xxx-exec-1
pass unclass2.t:xxx-while-1
pass unclass2.t:xxx-status-1
FAIL unclass2.t:xxx-status-2
pass unclass2.t:xxx-clean-chars-1
fail unclass2.t:xxx-param-subst-qmark-1 (as expected)
pass unclass2.t:xxx-param-_-1
pass unclass2.t:env-prompt
FAIL integer.t:integer-base-err-1
FAIL integer.t:integer-base-err-2
FAIL integer.t:integer-base-err-3
FAIL integer.t:integer-base-err-4
pass integer.t:integer-base-1
pass integer.t:integer-base-2
pass integer.t:integer-base-3
pass integer.t:integer-base-4
pass integer.t:integer-base-5
pass integer.t:integer-base-6
pass integer.t:integer-base-7
Total failed: 10 (7 unexpected)
Total passed: 185
[vax-linux:root]:(~/rpmbuild/BUILD/pdksh-5.2.14)#
```

[image: pdksh v5.2.14 on mandriva 2011]